# check if there is a string data in specific port on bash script

Tags: linux, bash, cat, netcat

I want to make a program with bash script, that can check if there is a string data from specific port in my machine. Can you help me with this programming? thanks... *sorry for my bad english

example:
*my machine port 7090, and if there is a string data receive in that port then execute a line of bash program else execute another program

```
if(there is a string data in port)
{
  read data from that port
}
else
{
  print data to another port
}
```

How to make bash script to check "there is a string data in port"?

Answer (score 0):

Why I Think its related to question asked in the  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070526/command-line-connect-to-tcp-port-read-data-match-pattern-print-true-or-falselink)

Click above link to check the related forum on stackoverflow

Comment: i think, that work if i know format data in that port. How when i didn't know the data format?

Comment: That you can verify first via catwalks answer there `echo "GET /"|netcat google.com 80`

Comment: how to make it a conditional if(), if there is string data that receive in my machine port?

Comment: I am not sure but can use character count wc or grep -c and check with pipe in between

Comment: Other members can give you exact answers
Even I looking forward how it will work for your solution also don't forget to post correct answer which worked for you